# Вывести значение из списка которая находится в словаре

Tags: python, list, словари

Есть задание.

```
a = {'Civil Engineering': ['Thomas', 'Benjamin', 'Franklin'],
             'Psycology': ['Joe', 'Chedwick', 'Helena']}
```

Надо использовать одно имя из списка, который является значением у словаря, для выведения утверждения об этом ученике, чтобы получилось как-то так:
`This is Franklin. He studies Civil Engineering`.
Без понятия как вывести значение из списка в словаре

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант. Имеем обычную проверку на включение в список с итерацией по словарю:

```
name = 'Thomas'

for k, v in a.items():
    print('This is {}. He studies {}'.format(name, k)) if name in v else None
```

Можно пойти другим путем с "выворачиванием" словаря в ключи-имена и значения-предметы, но тут должны быть уникальные ученики:

```
a = {'Civil Engineering': ['Thomas', 'Benjamin', 'Franklin'],
     'Psycology': ['Joe', 'Chedwick', 'Helena']}

name = 'Thomas'
subj = {}
for k, v in a.items():
    subj.update(dict.fromkeys(v, k))

print('This is {}. He studies {}'.format(name, subj[name])) if subj.get(name) else None
```

Answer (score 0):

получение значения из словоря:

```py
a = {'Civil Engineering': ['Thomas', 'Benjamin', 'Franklin'],
     'Psycology': ['Joe', 'Chedwick', 'Helena']}

print(a["Psycology"])
```

Соответственно получение значения из списка

```py
print(a["Psycology"][0])
```

Итого в вашем случае может сработать что то вроде

```py
for key in a.keys():
    for person in a[key]:
        print(f"This is {person}. He studies {key}")
```

Так же рекомендую прочитать вот это
https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/slovari-dict-funkcii-i-metody-slovarej.html
и вот это
https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/spiski-list-funkcii-i-metody-spiskov.html

Comment: Мне кажется, что Вы немного другую задачу решили. Здесь вопрос: `Надо использовать одно имя из списка, который является значением у словаря, для выведения утверждения об этом ученике`